# Flutter Takes two taps/clicks to change `ontap` colour change

Tags: flutter

The `parent widget` lists the same `child widget` two times. So there are two clickable `SVG images`. My intention is to change colour to `purple` when clicked and colour to `grey` when clicked again. It's like toggling colours (checking unchecking etc). The issue is when I click one `SVG image` of first one, then I can't `uncheck` (change colours) of the second one and vise-versa. It seems like the two widgets use the same `svgColourFilled` variable. But I'm not quite sure what the real issue of the code is.

**Error:** No errors, but colour change takes two clicks than one click to change colours if you click 1st image then try to check or uncheck the other one.

**Parent Widget**

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 final String svgTap1Path = './lib/Assets/svgs/forTools/Tap1.svg';
 final String svgTap2Path = './lib/Assets/svgs/forTools/Tap2.svg';

  
class ToolPanel extends StatefulWidget {
      
const ToolPanel( {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
  State<ToolPanel> createState() => _ToolPanelState();

  }

  class _ToolPanelState extends State<ToolPanel> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
          Row(
          
          children: [
            TwoSVGs(
                svgPicPath: svgTap1Path),

            TwoSVGs(
                svgPicPath: svgTap2Path)
                
                
                
                ])]);}}
```

**Child Widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

bool svgColourFilled = false;

class TwoSVGs extends StatefulWidget {


final String? svgPicPath;
final Color fillColour ;
final Color emptyColour ;

  const TwoSVGs(
    {Key? key, this.svgPicPath, this.fillColour = Colors.purple, this.emptyColour= Colors.grey}) : super(key: key);

 @override
  State<TwoSVGs> createState() => _TwoSVGsState();

  }

  class _TwoSVGsState extends State<TwoSVGs> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    

return Column(children: <Widget>[

  Container(

    

child: SizedBox ( width : 80, height : 80, child:


Material(
  
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.white,
                      onTap: () {
                                     
                        setState(() {  
                           
                          svgColourFilled = !svgColourFilled;

                          }
                    );
                    }, 

                    child: FittedBox(
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                                    widget.svgPicPath!,
                                    color: svgColourFilled == true
                                    ? widget.fillColour
                                    : widget.emptyColour
                                    
                                  )

                          )
                          
                          
                          ))


     ))]
                          ); 
                         } }
```

Comment: are you using global `svgColourFilled` variable as   question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code snippet, `bool svgColourFilled = false;`is global and used by both `TwoSVGs()`, put it inside state class.

```dart
class _TwoSVGsState extends State<TwoSVGs> {
  bool svgColourFilled = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```